# How to mock the mongoTemplate Object using Mockito FrameWork?

Tags: java, mockito

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class EmailServiceTest {

//    @InjectMocks
    private EmailService emailService;

    @Mock
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Mock
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Mock
    private FileStorageProperties fileStorageProperties;

    @Mock
    private Path fileStorageLocation;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What methods do you need from `MongoTemplate` that require mocking?

Comment: @Daniel I want to mock this mongoTemplate object so that i can mock some of mockTemplate methods like (mongoTemplate.findOne, mongoTemplate.aggregate).

Comment: I tried to pass this mongoTemplate mock object with Constructors to initialise it then it's working. is their any other way to mock this **mongoTemplate** object?

Comment: When you're mocking objects, you don't use constructors. You have to initialize the object as a Mock then mock the methods you want to use.